# Re-designing 37signals paths to be hosted under a single domain

Tags: naming-conventions, rest, 37-signals

37signals is a web app company. Some of their applications:

basecamp, to manage projects
highrise, to manage contacts
backpack, like a wiki

they use different domains for each application (basecamphq.com, highrisehq.com, etc)

in basecamp, this is the address of a particular comment for a post in a project of my company (acme) https://acme.basecamphq.com/projects/431678/posts/2964581/comments#5854236

if 37signals had chosen to host all the applications under their domain using folders (eg 37signals.com/basecamp/..., how would you design the paths RESTfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, how about something like

```
 http://www.37signals.com/[PRODUCTNAME]/projects/431678/posts/2964581/comments#5854236
```

Not quite sure what you're asking, really.

Comment: You didn't ask that to begin with.

Whether it is RESTful is subjective, I guess, given that REST is an architecture rather than a protocol.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#RESTful_web_services